# Synonym [file-move] and [file-moving]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[file-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-move) 62 questions and an excerpt

[file-moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-moving) 45 questions and no excerpt

There's no clear cut case for separate tags here. They both are describing the same process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are not enough qualified 'standard' users to carry a synonym proposal without assistance.

[file-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-move) has been applied slightly more often and has a Usage guide (of sorts!). It is also equally descriptive but slightly shorter.

Both tags describe the contents of the Qs to which they have been applied, neither is ambiguous, the concept is on topic for the site, the information added is very meaningful and although relevant across many languages etc, the meaning is consistent in all common contexts.

No Qs apply both tags. There are too few instances of application for analysis of All Time Top Answerers to be relevant. Neither has any watchers.

The case for a synonym is very strong, preferably as [file-moving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-moving) of [file-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-move), but requires mod assistance.